Ionizing smoke detectors as back-up to photoelectric
I am replacing all of my ionizing smoke detectors due to too-frequent false alarms in humid weather.  Also, I am unable to silence any false alarms as I am unable to climb to the ceiling to silence them.
The replacements will be smartphone enabled photo-electrics.  Now, I have numerous working ionizing alarms which could be possible back-ups, good in combination with the photo-electrics.  However, they cannot be placed on the ceiling due to my inability to reach them to silence any false alarms. Can I now place the ionizers lower on the wall since they will only be back-ups?

Placement is more touchy since smoke goes to ceiling first and then spreads.  I believe high on the wall near open doorways is preferred, but is old info.

Is there such a thing as a dual-sensor smart alarm?

You may be able to use a broom handle to reach the silence button?  Since they are backups, you can place them where you want.  As cripp659 has mentioned and as I have observed, having my house burnt down, the higher up they are the better.  That's where the smoke is.  Six inches below the ceiling is still good. A foot below the ceiling is not going to be of much use.
The best places to install them is indeed near doorways, especially just outside the bedrooms.
One place that no one puts them (except myself, because of my house fire) is actually in the ceiling space (or attic space).  The smoke actually travels there first.  If you have access to it, I would install a few there.

The broom handle approach won't work for me because, not only do I have balance issues which prevent me from climbing to the ceiling, my arm disability keeps me from reaching overhead with any implement....The new photoelectric detectors are all placed in the correct locations....I am only asking whether the still- working ionizing ones can be placed lower as backups, or whether I should toss them.

Personally I h ave both types in my house because why not be able to protect against more kinds of fire?

@EGall  Smoke alarms have a recommended ten life.  Any over seven years will have limited time left, so maybe newer ones with remote(if available) might be more useful.

All the ionizing detectors with faulty alarms were replaced in the last year or so...They had 10 year batteries...The false alarms have been caused by high climate humidity.  They were not installed close to bathrooms or kitchens...They were installed on the ceilings of 6 rooms.

Problem with smokes in the attic space is that a vented attic's conditions are way outside what smoke alarms are rated to take.

As you state, photoelectric smoke detectors are less sensitive in some cases than ionization-based detectors. That makes them good choices for a kitchens or garage, where there is smoke from cooking or car exhaust, but they should be supplemented by ionization smoke alarms.
In a comment, you mention, "I have balance issues... [and an] arm disability." That makes it even more important to get an early alert to fire, so that you have time to leave safely.
However, though I found many photoelectric smoke detectors with remote controls, either a dedicated control or using a WiFi-enabled device such as phone, I could not find an ionization alarm with remote shut-off.
Workaround
Since this is a DIY site, then I'd suggest using one or more inexpensive ionization-based alarms, with an addition to silence it more easily. Here are a few ways to do so.

Attach a lever to the face of the alarm, so that a pull on one end of the lever pushes the silence button, and fasten a string to the lever. Disadvantage: if the button requires a hard push, then a hard tug on the cord might dislodge the alarm or the lever.
Add an easily-activated microswitch in parallel with the existing silence switch, and attach a light string, or even heavy sewing thread, to shut it. Disadvantage: requires surgery on alarm.
Add a wire pair in parallel with the existing silence switch, and a push-button switch at the bottom of the wires to shut it. Disadvantage: requires surgery on alarm.

Caveat
Of course, any change to the alarm would void its warranty, and might reduce its effectiveness. However, this is only intended as a supplement to the photoelectric detectors, not as the sole alarm.

My concern would be that any modification to the alarm would be unacceptable to the home insurer and harm your insurance coverage.
